# Regarding list of tuples and file

Tags: haskell

I need to take the list of tuples from a file and multiple 2nd a 3rd values of each tuple. For example: [(1,"A", 100,2),(2,"B", 50,3)] . I need to find 100*2=200 and 50* 3=150. I only want to display the final total. That is 350. I am taking the list of tuples from a file. I am getting an error lik this:

```
- Type error in generator
*** Term           : generator c
*** Type           : Int
*** Does not match : IO a
```

Code is given below.

```
type Code=Int
type Price=Int
type Quantity=Int
type Name=String
type ProductDatabase=(Code,Name,Price,Quantity)  
 bill=do
           b<-cart_list_returner     
           let c :: [ProductDatabase]
               c = b    
           w<-generator c
           let r :: String
               r = w
           putStrLn r

    generator::[ProductDatabase]->Int
    generator c=foldl (\a (id,x, y, z) -> a + y*z) 0 c
```

I just want the program to take the list of tuples in file and produce the total amount. Some one plz help me. thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe it was better to formulate one normal question than asking a lot of similar questions about that [(1,"A", 100,2),(2,"B", 50,3)] list?

Comment: @dmitry.malikov: Sir, actually i am not an expert in Haskell. Just doing a small assignment in it. That's why different issues are coming. Anyways sorry for asking too many questions about same issue.

Comment: @Roy: If these questions are related to an assignment, you should probably tag them as "homework". Furthermore, it would be great if you could go through all your questions and accept correct answers: thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `<-` binding operator only when you want to run an IO function.

For giving names to results of pure functions, use `let`.

`generator` is a pure function --- its result is of type `Int`, not of type `IO Int`.

So replace the line

```
       w<-generator c
```

with

```
       let w = generator c
```

Comment: @Roy confirm the result of `cart_list_returner` is as you expect by adding the line `print b`.

Comment: @Roy if that answer is correct you can accept it. It is how that process should work actually.